# How do I call the function URL for an AWS Lambda that takes in APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-lambda

I have developed an AWS Lambda function using the AWS Console. The URL for this function is https://mi7ark5tunresgw25fdjstovuq0woylg.lambda-url.us-west-1.on.aws/.

This function can be tested using the AWS Console.

The input JSON for testing is:

```json
{
  "Body": "Q0FDREJBQUItOEFBQi00QUFFLTlBQUUtNkFBQUFBQWNkM2U5"
}
```

[image]

The function returns a JSON response.

Here is the C# code for the Lambda function:

```cs
public APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest oldKey, ILambdaContext context)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions option = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    if (oldKey.Body.Length != 48) return (new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable,
        Body = JsonSerializer.Serialize<string>(string.Empty, option),
    });

    string newKey = string.Empty;
    dcLicense.Extend(oldKey.Body, out newKey);

    return (new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Body = JsonSerializer.Serialize<string>(newKey, option),
    });
}
```

I am looking to call this function from a .NET Framework 4.8 application & get the output string.

Is there any simple sample code for this?

Comment: Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples)?

Comment: Or [this](https://medium.com/adessoturkey/refit-c-implementation-guide-5d27ee43d75d)?  (Refit is nice since it hides the low level stuff.)

Comment: You need to use the authentication method that is being used by the server.  Net 4.8 used Windows Credentials which latest AWS uses OAUTH2.  So if you are targeting Net 4.8 you need to modify code to use OAUTH2 authentication.  OATH2 is a two step authentication where you request a token (cookie) and then use the cookie with each query. See : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/implement-oauth-2-0-device-grant-flow-by-using-amazon-cognito-and-aws-lambda/.  Token code should be the same in 4.8 and Core.

Comment: None of these suggestions address how the JSON data is fed into the function. Also, the last suggestion is way too complicated. I just feel that there should be a simple solution to this.

Comment: @jdweng No authentication is needed if the `NONE` auth type is selected when creating a function URL.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary : Do you know that NONE is selected?  Most systems have switched to OAUTH2.  The OP need to step through code and find out if it is using the new key (length 4) or old key.  Old key probably won't work.  Proxy may not work with old code.  Error could be due to proxy.

Comment: The fact that they’ve named their variable `oldKey` has **nothing** to do with authorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to trigger your Lambda function over the public internet, which I assume is the case since you've created a (publicly accessible) function URL, you can easily achieve this by making an HTTP request from your .NET Framework application.

When the Lambda function is triggered via the Function URL, the incoming request is a JSON object that is passed to the Lambda. This object contains various details such as the HTTP method, query string values, request body etc. This is what defines what the `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` object will contain, that you've configured your Lambda to accept.

*Inside* the API Gateway console, you have the ability to define an `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` object to use as a test event. Your test event (or what you refer slightly incorrectly to as the 'input JSON') is essentially a `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` object with its `Body` set to `Q0F...`.

However, *outside* of the API Gateway console, we don't have the ability to manually create a test event. Instead, AWS maps the request to the event that your Lambda accepts.

Since you only use the `Body` from `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` (`oldKey.Body`), all we need to do is pass `Q0F...` to the API Gateway. This will then be mapped to create the exact test event you have defined above - a request object with the `Body` set to `Q0F...`.

Note other fields, like headers, are also set accordingly but since you don't use them, we don't need to set them for the HTTP request.

This will work:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    var lambdaUrl = "https://mi7ark5tunresgw25fdjstovuq0woylg.lambda-url.us-west-1.on.aws/";
    var functionInput = "Q0FDREJBQUItOEFBQi00QUFFLTlBQUUtNkFBQUFBQWNkM2U5";

    using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
      var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(lambdaUrl, new StringContent(functionInput));
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + responseBody);
      } else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to get response with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Received status code NotAcceptable. I guess the URL does not accept Post command.

Comment: @T.J.Fan Can you add your function code in the question? It should be a POST if you’re passing that body through… and add a screenshot of your input and output when testing via the console please.

Comment: I've changed the original post to use all actual code snippets as I couldn't do this in the comment section. Hope this helps and thank you for all the help.

Comment: @T.J.Fan Ah, since you're using `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest`, your input to the actual Lambda is just the body value itself (you're saying the `Body` is `x` and not `Body = x`). Editing the answer now.

Comment: @T.J.Fan No worries, enjoy using AWS :)